# ASP.NET Design Deterioration When Routing

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, routes

I use routing for my menu link in ASP.NET Webforms.

This is my Global.asax code:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
public void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("homepage", "TestProject/Homepage", "~/pages/Default.aspx");
}
```

And my example usage is as follows (this code is in my master page btw):

```
<li><a href="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/TestProject/Homepage") %>" class="active">Home Page</a></li>
```

When I run default.aspx, the design is normal. But when I click this menu or other menus, the design is distorted, the logo is disappearing etc.

For example:

This is my normal slider when I run the Default.aspx normally:
[Normal Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ce0fQ.png)

And this is my broken slider design when I click Home Page on the menu:
[Broken Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19Ain.png)

What is the cause of this problem? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Is the path to your CSS stylesheet still correct in your broken page?

Comment: I think it was not. I fix this and now it's working. You can check my answer if you want. @NamelessLambda

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem. If someone encounter this problem they can benefit as follows:

Before resolving the problem my CSS and JavaScripts like this:

```
<link href="Content/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Content/css/bs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Content/js/cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Content/js/colorswitcher.js"></script>
```

After solving the problem:

```
<link href="<%=ResolveUrl("Content/css/style.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<%=ResolveUrl("Content/css/bs.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("Content/js/cookie.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("Content/js/colorswitcher.js") %>"></script>
```